# How to deal with Weird records in FLAT FILE?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, batch-file

SSIS falls flat on it back with this scenario .

In my flat file, we have Normal looking records like this

```
"1","2","STATUSCHANGED","A","02-MAY-12 21:52:34","","Re","Initial review",""
```

And some like this ; ( record spread over several lines )

```
"1","2","SALESNOTIFICATIONRESPOND","Ac","02-MAY-12 21:55:19","From: W, J 
Sent: Wednesday, May 08, 2012 2:00 PM
To: XXXX, A; Acost
Subject: RE: Notification Id 1219 - Qu ID XXXXXX 
I got this from earlier today. Our team is reviewing the request. 



Thanks, 

Hi,

This account belongs to D please approve/deny.

Thanks!

Claud","","","Reassign"
```

So looking at the file in NOTEPAD + which is amazing it shows me that within that field that is spread over several line, I should take out all the {CR}{LF} in that field.

The row delimiter for this file is LF and the text qualifier is “.

So 2 things I need to do on a collection of 200 file ?

1. Remove all the {CR}{LF} in the file ?
2. Remove any embedded “ in the actual fields as “ is the text qualifier ?

Anyone have any idea how to do this in windows , dos or vba for such a large number of files so its automated ?

Answer (score 3):

For data such as this, I prefer using a Script Component to perform the parse. I wrote a [blog post describing one approach](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2010/05/18/ssis-design-pattern-loading-variable-length-rows.aspx).

Hope this helps,
Andy

Answer (score 1):

Powershell will do this for you for the {CR}{LF} but it might take you a while to code if you have never used powershell before.

The " qualifier appearing in the middle of fields is a real mess, you may be able to develop rules to clean this up but there is no guarantee that you will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

If the proper row terminator is just LF and you are certain that every row is properly terminated by LF then you can remove all {CR}{LF}, but you should not actually need to.  As long as they {CR}{LF} is properly inside a pair of text qualifiers, it should just be imported literally.

And yes, you definitely need to remove any text qualifiers (or escape them, as you prefer) from within an actual field when the entire field is surrounded by text qualifiers.  That will cause confusion.

Personally, I would approach this by either writing a [python](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/python-for-the-sql-server-dba/) script to preprocess the data before feeding it to SSIS or just have the script import the entire thing into SQL for me.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andy. I had a similar issue and I took care of it with a script component task.
Your code could look something like this (doesnt handle the CR LF issue)

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper

<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute> _
<CLSCompliant(False)> _
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent

    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        Dim strRow As String
        Dim strColSeperator As String
        Dim rowValues As String()
        strRow = Row.Line.ToString()
        If strRow.Contains(",") Then
            strColSeperator = (",")
        ElseIf strRow.Contains(";") Then
            strColSeperator = ";"
        End If

        rowValues = Row.Line.Split(CChar(strColSeperator))
        If (rowValues.Length > 1) Then
            Row.Code = rowValues.GetValue(0).ToString()
            Row.Description = rowValues.GetValue(1).ToString()
            Row.Blank = rowValues.GetValue(2).ToString()
            Row.Weight = rowValues.GetValue(3).ToString()
            Row.Scan = rowValues.GetValue(4).ToString()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

A step by step tutorial is available at [Andy Mitchell's post](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/The-Script-Component-as-a-Transformation.aspx)